# How to set max string length in Solr configuration

Tags: solr, solrj, solr5

while indexing with SolrJ, I was able to find that, one of my data was impossible to index. Because the length of data(String) was more then 20000.
with my googling,  was used for the length(before Solr 4.x) and it is now used with . hence I just applied it to my Solr but still it is not working.

if anyone know, how to increase string length in Solr5. please give me your advices.

below sudo code is my part of Schema.

```
<field name ="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class= " ..." />
<filter class= ".. " />
...
<filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxToeknCount="100000" />
</analyzer>

 <analyzer type ="query">
   ...
   ...
  <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxToeknCount="100000" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pay attention to the parameter `maxToeknCount` it is misspelled. The correct one should be `maxTokenCount`, this could be the root of your problems.

Anyway, I don't understand why you're trying to extend LimitTokenCountFilterFactory limits instead to remove it.
Removing the filter `LimitTokenCountFilterFactory` from `index` and `query` analyser should fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the misspelled. I typed the code by hand-typing but copying for codes.

Comment: as you mentioned, I just removed LimitTokenCountFilterFactory and re-executed indexing but it still gives an error message. any other idea??

Comment: with unknown reason, I just solved the issue above. I just recreated core and reconstructed schema and solrconfig then, it worked somehow. thank you for your help.